# PostgreSQL master slave streaming replication slave shutting down

Tags: postgresql

We have master slave streaming replication on Prod server, slave is getting shut down automatically. I'm not able to figure out why slave server is going shut down
please help.

```
10:17:17.164 ISTLOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:07.482 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]
10:34:11.675 ISTPANIC:  could not open file "pg_wal/0000000100000216000000E7": Operation not permitted
10:34:11.702 ISTLOG:  startup process (PID 12602) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
10:34:11.702 ISTLOG:  terminating any other active server processes
10:34:11.848 ISTLOG:  database system is shut down
10:36:47.455 ISTLOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is not supported by this build
10:36:47.455 ISTHINT:  Compile with --with-openssl to use SSL connections.
10:36:47.455 ISTCONTEXT:  line 128 of configuration file "/op_tig/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf"
10:36:47.460 ISTLOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2022-06-14 11:00:07 IST
10:36:47.460 ISTHINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
stat ‘/archive/restore_wal/00000002.history’: No such file or directory
10:37:29.110 ISTLOG:  entering standby mode
stat ‘/archive/restore_wal/0000000100000216000000E6’: No such file or directory
10:37:29.121 ISTLOG:  redo starts at 216/E6714F28
10:37:29.169 ISTLOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 216/E6F42188
10:37:29.170 ISTLOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
stat ‘/archive/restore_wal/0000000100000216000000E7’: No such file or directory
10:37:29.180 ISTLOG:  invalid resource manager ID 130 at 216/E7023648
10:37:29.256 ISTLOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 216/E7000000 on timeline 1
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please add all of the `wal` settings from the `postgresql.conf` file of your server.

Comment: That's an `EPERM`, I guess. Please show what operating system you are using, what the permissions on the file are and how the file was created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the slave server master server is running fine, `wal` settings I have done on the slave extra are `wal_level = replica`  and master `archive_mode = on`             
`archive_command = 'cp %p /path/%f'`  `max_wal_senders = 10`       
`wal_keep_segments = 64`